# For any convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, $\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\, \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \,\, |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(x_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then,  $\forall \epsilon > 0 \,\, \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \,\, |x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$ true? If so, can anyone present proof?

Comment: Any convergent sequence is Cauchy

Comment: But isn't Cauchy $|x_{m} - x_n| < \epsilon$?

Comment: Choose $m= n+1$

Comment: oh yeah. right. Just got confused for no reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let L be the limit of the sequence. If $$|x_{n+1}-L|<{\epsilon\over 2}$$ and $$|x_{n}-L|<{\epsilon\over 2}$$ what can you conclude about $$|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|$$ (Use the Triangle Inequality)

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n \to x$ then is Cauchy. Given $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $n_0(\varepsilon) $ such that $|x_n-x_m|< \varepsilon$ for all $n,m\ge n_0(\varepsilon)$. In particular $|x_{n+1}-x_n|< \varepsilon$ for $n\ge n_0(\varepsilon)$